# Help connecting claw foot shower piece

Tags: plumbing

I got this claw foot shower kit from Home Depot. I can get everything connected except these two pieces which attach the base faucet to the pipe going up to the shower head. The shower pipe fits into the hole here but there is no way to secure and no pieces came with. Do I need a compression sleeve?  See pics for details.

[image: pieces]

[image: inside of second piece and nut]

[image: instructions]

[image: tap assembly]

Comment: Which brand and model is the kit you purchased?

Comment: What do the instructions say? Maybe post a photo of the diagram and explain why you can't accomplish what it shows.

Comment: It is a Pegasus https://www.homedepot.com/p/Pegasus-3-Handle-Claw-Foot-Tub-Faucet-with-Gooseneck-Spout-Riser-and-Hand-Shower-for-Acrylic-Tub-in-Brushed-Nickel-4024-PL-SN/100482024

Comment: There are no instructions. Literally just a sketch of the finished product.

Comment: There is a link to instruction the Home Depot site you linked - does that help at all? https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/66/66264db2-5c7a-472e-8407-c0ebe81af962.pdf

Comment: It looks like you may be missing some part (s)

Comment: please post a photo of the tap assembly

Comment: Thanks for the link to the instructions. I feel like an idiot. I looked for them but couldn’t seem to find them.

Comment: From that list it does seem like I’m missing something but there are no pics and some of the pieces came preassembled so it’s hard to tell.   I think I’ll try to take it back.  I did post above a photo of the valve assembly. The small piece screws into the top and the rise is supposed to fit into that, but that’s the part that just slips in that hole but there’s nothing to hold it on.